# Python retorna "Morto" ao tentar ler json > 240mb

Tags: mysql, python, json, arquivo

O problema ocorre em um server CentOS versão 6.8 final.
O mesmo script com outro arquivo menor funciona perfeitamente.

Teste efetuados em Ubuntu 16.04 o processo ocorre com sucesso.

Alguma solução? Segue abaixo o code.

[código no gist](https://gist.github.com/vanessasoutoc/3c1507bd82f527da979d8823883278e0)

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente. Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Comment: Outra dica é: cole diretamente seus códigos na sua pergunta. E de preferência, somente o trecho onde o erro aparece. Acredito que seja difícil alguém parar para ler e entender suas 250 linhas de código.

Comment: Pensando um pouco aqui, como seu json eh um pouco grande, talvez ao tentar lê-lo na memória, seu PC trave. Tente altera a linha onde você lê o json (`jsonToPython = json.load(data_file)`) para utilizar a biblioteca como a [ijson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) ou a [json-streamer](https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/json-streamer)

Comment: Valeu... funcionou... https://gist.github.com/vanessasoutoc/e82a76fc7d3e45dade9ca4315c0e4b40

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu! :) Se a resposta solucionou seu problema, você deve [aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) para marcar sua pergunta como "já respondida".

Answer (score 1):

Como seu `JSON` eh um pouco grande, ao tentar lê-lo na memória, seu PC pode travar por falta de memória.

Sendo assim, tente alterar a linha onde você lê o `JSON`:

```
jsonToPython = json.load(data_file)
```

para utilizar uma biblioteca como a [ijson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) ou a [json-streamer](https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/json-streamer), que são específicas para manipulação de arquivos com grande volume de dados.